# How to set url map routing for all pages?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, routes

I want to get a name in url and then redirect to original page for example:

```
 <facebook.com/mat/default.aspx> to <facebook.com/default.aspx>
```

with map routing i can do this like :

```
routes.MapPageRoute("userName_map", "{userName}/default","~/default.aspx");
```

but i cant do this for every page.i want a solution for all page
what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

If they all go to "~/default.aspx", you can do this using a wildcard:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("userName_map", "{*userName}", "~/default.aspx");
```

The asterisk * tells it that anything past {userName}/ is to apply to this rule.

Hope this helps! Good Luck!